# Is $Z(G)\subset Z(\chi)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

I want to prove that for a finite group $G,$ if we are given a representation $X: G\to GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ with character $\chi: G\to \mathbb{C}$ then the center of the group is inside the center of the character (actually I am not even sure if this is true). So I want to show $Z(G)\subset Z(\chi)$.

Let $g\in Z(G)$. I need to show $\vert \chi(g) \vert =\chi(1)$. We know that $X(g)X(h)=X(h)X(g) \forall h\in H$. I know that **if $X(g)$ would commute with all the matrices of $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$** then we would have $X(g)=\lambda I_n$ with $\lambda$ a $n$-th root of unity. Then $\chi(g)=tr(X(g))=\lambda \chi(1)$ so $\vert \chi(g) \vert = \chi(1)$ so we would have $g\in Z(G)$.

I'm not sure the statement in bold is true.

Also is it true that if $~\ker(\chi)=1$ then $Z(G)=Z(\chi)$?

**Edit**

Since $X(g)X(h)=X(h)X(g)\forall h\in G$ we know that $X(g)$ is a homomorphism of representation. So if $X$ is irreducible, using Schur lemma, we get $X(g)=\lambda I_n$, so again $\vert\chi(g)\vert=\vert \lambda \vert \chi(1)=\chi(1)$. Now I want to try to extend : I know the irreducible characters form an orthonormal basis for central functions on $G$. So let $\chi$ be any character. We have $\chi=a_1 \chi_1+\ldots a_n \chi_n$. Then $\chi(g)=a_1\chi_1(g)+\ldots a_n\chi_n(g)$ but then I don't really understand how to conclude.

**Concerning $~\ker(\chi)=1$ then $Z(G)=Z(\chi)$ :**

If I have proven already $Z(G)\subset Z(\chi)$, I just need to prove $Z(\chi) \subset Z(g)$. Take $g\in Z(\chi)$ this means $X(g)=\lambda I_n$, for some $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$. Then we need to show $gh=hg, \forall h\in G$ since we assumed $Ker(\chi)=1$, what we have to show is that $\chi(gh)=\chi(hg)$. But this is true since $X(gh)=X(g)X(h)=\lambda I_n X(h)=X(h)\lambda I_n=X(h)X(g)=X(hg)$.

Comment: Since $g$ is central, the map $X(g)$ is in fact a homomorphism of representations. So this should help you in the case of the representation being irreducible. To extend from that should also not be too hard.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I edited my post. Also, what about $~\ker(\chi)=1 \implies Z(G)=Z(\chi)$?

Comment: If you cannot prove something, try to build a counterexample.

Comment: You need $\chi$ to be irreducible to conclude. Consider for example the regular representation.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, because the regular representation has trace $0$? So actually the regular representation is never irreducible exept if the group has only one element $\vert G \vert = \{1\}$?